# CoreData context returns nil after setting it up

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to set up `coreData` but for some reason my `context` returns `nil` making it impossible to `store`, `fetch` or `save` data. I have used the same `context` code in another project an it works fine, so not sure what's up this time. The context looks like this:

```
func getContext() -> NSPersistentContainer {
    let persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyContainer")

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })

        return container
    }()
    return persistentContainer
}
```

Then in `viewWillAppear`

```
context = getContext().viewContext
print("", context) //This is nil
```

So what am I doing wrong? Can the naming of the `container` be whatever I want or does it has to be something specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name should be the same as `.XCDataModel` file in your project.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640579-name)

[How File looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gnic4.png)

In this case you should create container in that way:
`let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CardGenerator")`

Comment: Ah, of course! I thought it was supposed to be the same as the project name for some reason. Makes sense, thanks!